# MX Cloner "not authorized" error

Tags: mx-cloner

Using MX Cloner (v 1.2.4) with EE 2.9.2 I get this error when saving a "cloned" entry:

"You are not authorized to perform this action"

From what I can tell, this only happens when the entry has a "Grid" element in it.  The entry looks good, but just won't save.  I'm logged in as the admin user.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Version 1.2.5 is available for [download](https://github.com/MaxLazar/mx_cloner).

Grid field has new methods for fields validation which asked for new way to do entry clone. I hope that new update helps you.

Comment: Wow - awesome!  Works great!  Thanks a lot for the fast update.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have the same error with some entries but not others.
I'm using MX Cloner 1.2.7 with EE 2.9.2
I can't nai ldown any differences between the entry i am able to clone and the one i am not. They use the same channel and channel fields. Any thoughts?

Comment: Needs to have more info - needs to see what field this entry used for example. If your CP avalible online - send me message to max at eec.ms